# Setting up a sitemap with Django

Tags: django, django-urls

I am having some problems with sitemaps.

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import sitemaps
from oportunidade.views import OportunidadeSitemap
sitemaps = {'oportunidade': OportunidadeSitemap}
...
    url(r'^sitemap\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': sitemaps}),
```

views.py

```
...
class OportunidadeSitemap(Sitemap):
    changefreq = "never"
    priority = 0.5

    def items(self):
        return Oportunidade.objects.filter(ativo=True)

    def lastmod(self, obj):
        return obj.ultima_alteracao
```

But I get the following error when I access http://localhost:8000/sitemap.xml
***'Oportunidade' object has no attribute 'get_absolute_url'***

Here is my "Oportunidade" model:

```
class Oportunidade(models.Model):

    user = models.ForeignKey(User)    

    titulo = models.CharField('Titulo',max_length=31)

 ...
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.titulo
```

I am very confused how to set sitemap.

Comment: Can you please post your Oportunidade object code?

Comment: I updated the question with the model. I am very confuse about it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look at [Django's sitemap class reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-class-reference). Although you implement the necessary `items` method, you seem to be missing either the `location` method (or attribute) in your sitemap or the [`get_absolute_url`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) method in you model class.

> If `location` isn't provided, the framework will call the `get_absolute_url()` method on each object as returned by items().

Easiest way to go forward would be to implement `get_absolute_url()` in you `Oportunidade` model class.

Answer (score 1):

According to the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#sitemap-class-reference

If you don't provide a location for the sitemap class, it will look for get_absolute_url on each object.

So, you'll either need to specify a location property on your sitemap class, or get_absolute_url on your object. That should get you going.